# Commericaly available resistive surface

Tags: resistors, resistance, potentiometer, touchscreen

As you all know one can experiment with drawing graphite patterns on paper for forming improvised potentiometer-like-surfaces

[image]

So I was wondering If there's some sort of commercially available resistive materials that could be used for similar tasks, but more sustainable. Are carbon fiber sheets good for this? Material should be lightweight and sturdy, I'd like to try and make a diy resistive touch screen with it. Transparency would be a plus.

Comment: What use would a non-transparent touch-screen membrane be? (Grin.) Conductive film touchscreens were usually made with rows and columns on facing layers, sometimes with embossed dots in the gaps to keep them apart. The rows and columns were multiplex-scanned to figure out the coordinates of the touch.

Comment: @Transistor, `What use would a non-transparent touch-screen membrane be?` Digital finger painting? Maybe? Or touchpads?

Comment: i think those screens use gold strips so thin you can see through it. there is conductive paint, sold at maker outlets in small batches, but for a screen you would be better off with capacitive sensors on the side, charting the finger disruptions into a grid

Comment: carbon fiber only conducts along the fibers and it's insulated by resin. slider potentiometer carbon trace is made from just graphite and glue. you'd have to find graphite fine enough and mix it at about 70% with epoxy resin,which is some of the strongest resin you can find.

Comment: Indium tin oxide is transparent and colorless in thin layers and is commercially available at reasonable cost on various substrates (plastic, glass).  Search for _ITO glass_.

Comment: @dandavis yes, but I'm looking specifically for resistive screen, not a capacitive one

Comment: @com.prehensible this looks like a good idea, except for the part that that epoxy is a good insulator, thus the mass wouls end up non-conductive. Also it's too thick to mix it with fine grains. Super glue might work but then theres also a a factor that homemade material will not have a well distributed consistency thus will not accurate.

Comment: On youtube there are methods with polypro transparent sleeves with high grade graphite buffed onto it with a paper cloth and then buffed very flat with a neoprene sander pad, the more thin is the graphite the lower the resistivity. https://youtu.be/Z74i-GG3vnY

Answer (score 1):

There's some videos here of people making conductive surfaces in easy lab processes: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZVCpOIdTT9g

Here is a kind of paint that is transparent,the same that touchscreens are made of, that you can perhaps paint on a statue to render it resistive:
Chinese version: https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/50ml-high-conductivity-PEDOT-PSS-up-to-500S-cm-as-same-as-clevios-PH500-made-in/32258862429.html
RnD lab version: https://www.ossila.com/products/pedot-pss

You can mistakenly buy an industrial product and find that it's an antistatic coating rather than for touchscreens. You can mess around with an antistatic bag and see if it works, they come in A4 sizes.

It will be difficult to source from an units reseller. *Intrinsically conductive polymers like polyanilines, polypyrrols and polythiophenes become conductive by removing an electron from their conjugated [π-orbitals via doping](https://www.heraeus.com/en/group/products_and_solutions_group/conductive_polymers/cpolymers/conductive-polymers.aspx)*.
Here's one. It's got [5 wires and it's transparent](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/Win10-Compatible-17-inch-touch-panel-5-wire-resistive-touch-screen-17-inch-touchscreen-kiosk-with/32810464873.html?spm=a2g0w.search0204.3.46.28070353V4fNYU&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_1_10065_10344_10068_10342_10325_10546_10343_10340_10548_10341_10084_10083_10618_10305_10304_10615_10307_10313_10059_10184_10534_100031_10103_441_10624_442_10623_10622_10621_10620_10142,searchweb201603_25,ppcSwitch_4_ppcChannel&algo_expid=f01e5979-3058-479d-a385-5ab238f2b987-7&algo_pvid=f01e5979-3058-479d-a385-5ab238f2b987&priceBeautifyAB=0).

Carnegie Melon made a conductive spray paint to do touchscreen guitars and anything, it's not transparent... [it's this kind of thing.](https://hollandshielding.com/Conductive-coating?gclid=CjwKCAiA78XTBRBiEiwAGv7EKj-NvbPNBan7pCRjsTzgg2WUNjIfEgMwSLNi-AamQ7J7S-eu8ru3lhoCjdkQAvD_BwE)

this is a demonstration of a product simply called electric paint
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PkeWxrw6lW0

Comment: I men raw materials

Comment: Hi, ok, I edited for the same material in liquid form it's called PEDOT, it's listed on "transparent conductive materials" wiki page and the industry leader is perhaps Hareus.com...

Comment: "Raw" material makes little sense. The raw material for transparent touch screen is sand and gold. Congrats!

Comment: they can also be solvent-setting plastics, synthesis: The electrons in these delocalized orbitals have high mobility when the material is "doped" by oxidation .... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conductive_polymer#Synthesis